# Use SmallDateType in Model-First Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I can't help but feel I am missing something but to this day I cannot find the answer.

I am doing a model-first entity framework and have a few properties set as DateTime.  These translate to DateTime in the database - but I would like to use SmallDateTime.  In my case, getting down to seconds and milliseconds just isn't worth the double storage for as many rows as I will have.

Does anyone know a way in the model-first environment to map DateTime to a SmallDateTime DB field?  As a last hope, I can generate the DDL, replace all, and update the Model from the database after - but I feel that is obnoxious!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a kind of tricky thing.

First of all read this article [Model first](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604113813/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/05/model-first-with-the-entity-framework-4.aspx) if you have not yet.

Then create separate class library project with custom `IGenerateActivityOutput` implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.OutputGenerators;
using System.Activities;

namespace MyCSDLToSSDL
{
    public class MyCsdlToSsdl: IGenerateActivityOutput
    {
        private CsdlToSsdl _generator;
        public MyCsdlToSsdl()
        {
            _generator = new CsdlToSsdl();
        }

        public T GenerateActivityOutput<T>(OutputGeneratorActivity owningActivity, NativeActivityContext context, IDictionary<string, object> inputs) where T : class
        {
            var str = _generator.GenerateActivityOutput<T>(owningActivity, context, inputs) as string;

            return str.Replace("Type=\"datetime\"", "Type=\"smalldatetime\"") as T;
        }

    }
}
```

The next step is to modify database generation workflow.

1. Locate TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml in your file system.
2. Copy this file to the same folder with different name. TablePerTypeStrategy_smalldatetime.xaml for example. Open it with VS.
3. Change `OutputGeneratorType` of `CsdlToSsdlAndMslActivity` to `"MyCSDLToSSDL.MyCsdlToSsdl, MyCSDLToSSDL"`. Double quotes are required.
4. Change database generation workflow property to "TablePerTypeStrategy_smalldatetime.xaml (VS)".
5. Try to generate database from model.

Looks very much like a workaround but it works. :) Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Both the way to do it as well as linking to an article for me to learn more.  Bounty well deserved :)

Comment: Actually I am having one issue - I seem to be missing the Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.OutputGenerators in my .NET references.  I have the Entity Power-Pack.  Is there anything else I would need?

Comment: It's in VS2010 install folder 
[install folder]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE